# Docker/Django reflects changes only once

Tags: django, docker, nginx

Whenever I make a change in a template, it will be reflected on the page. Every subsequent change is ignored. When I refresh page, it "shuffles" between original and first change. I am not a pro, but it looks like something with cacheing? I am not aware of caching anything though.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "3", "mysite.wsgi:application"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_files:/app/staticfiles
      - media_files:/app/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    image: nginx:stable-perl
    volumes:
      - static_files:/app/staticfiles
      - media_files:/app/media
      - ./nginx/user_conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./db_backup:/app/db_backup/
    env_file: .env
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: mail
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pw
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_files:
  media_files:
  pgadmin:
  db_backup:
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right about cache. By default django use [cached.Loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) for templates loading. You serve django app with gunicorn and start 3 workers. Each one with it's own cache. I recommend using [django dev server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver) for development.

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I have rebuilt the docker-compose which only runs django dev server and it seems to work. I will study more on this. One more thing I am curious about, if you could explan: right now in docker-compose under web service I have a command `python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, however in the Dockerfile at the end I have `CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "2", "my_project.wsgi"]` - which actually runs the server now? Gunicorn or django? I mean it works, but I dont understand it.

Comment: 'command' in docker-compose [overrides](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#command) default CMD from Dockerfile. Therefore django dev server runs your application